# KeyBinding to SWT Table or JFace TableViewer

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

In Eclipse E4, I am able to add keybinding to the part and it is working fine when the part is selected. My Part has a tableviewer in it. If the table is selected, the keybinding doesnt work.

I can add the key listener to the table and trigger the same key binding command but is there any way, where we can specify to make the keybinding for the part to work on the table which is present inside the part?

Comment: Key Binding for what? Bindings are to a command, what does the command do?

Comment: I am trying to add CTRL+A (SelectAll behaviour) to my tableviewer / table. I added the keybinding to te command which is working in the part level. When the table is selected it is not working. How to add make the keybinding (to a command) working on part, to work on the table as well? Also, on a different note, the key listener when added to the table, doesnt provide the state mask as expected. It is alwaya zero. Any help here as well?

Comment: Found answer for the second part of my comment above. i.e. able to get hold of CTRL+A using key listener, still wondering how to make it to work using the keybinding for commands. ie. how to add the keybinding (for command) to the table.

Comment: I don't have any problem with key bindings when a table is selected. Possibly it may be related to the particular binding - Ctrl+A may be something the native control that implements to table handles itself - I can't test that here are I use macOS which doesn't use that.